# Overwrite one method in c++ class

Tags: c++

If I have this class:

```
class FooBar {
    public:
        FooBar(int qux);
        void bar();

        void foo1();
        void foo2();
        //...
        void foo99();
}
```

How can I overwrite the `bar` method in `FooBar`, while still being able to use all the other `foo` method without defining them again?

**Edit:**

I want to use like this:

```
FooBar2 baz(1); // call the constructor of FooBar, FooBar(1)
baz.foo1(); //call method foo1 of original FooBar
baz.bar(); // call method bar of FooBar2
```

I prefer **not** to edit the header or implementation of FooBar.

Is it also possible to make the constructor function call the original constructor function from `FooBar`?

Comment: Do you mean overriding, or overloading?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive - what do you actually want? Provide real context; `foo` and `bar` are meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

You make `bar` `virtual`, because overriding only applies to `virtual` methods.

Then you extend `FooBar` and provide a new implementation just for `bar`.

```
class FooBar {
    public:
        virtual void bar();

        void foo1();
        void foo2();
        //...
        void foo99();
};

class FooBarDerived : FooBar
{
    public:
        void bar();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance.

```
class FooBar
{
public:
    virtual void bar() { ... default implementation ... }
    void foo1();
    void foo99();
}


class FooBarVariation : public FooBar
{
public:
    virtual void bar() { ... different implementation ... }
}
```

`FooBarVariation` will act like a `FooBar`, but with a different implementation of `bar()`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is ***Function Hiding*** and not ***overridding***.
Overidding applies only when the `virtual` keyword is involved.

Just redefine the method you want to overload in your derived class and you should be fine.

```
class YourClass: public FooBar 
{
    public:
       void bar(){}
};
```

The class `YourClass` objects can access all the methods of `FooBar` because those are `public` methods and your class derives publically from it, while `YourClass::bar()` ***hides*** `FooBar::bar()`.

**EDIT:**
Your edited question makes it clear that ***Function Hiding*** is indeed what you need.
Here is a **[online demo](http://ideone.com/w18Gj)** of function hiding achieving what your requirement is.

> **Is it also possible to make the constructor function call the original constructor function from `FooBar`?**

You can use the ***Member Initialization list*** to call appropriate Base class constructor through derived class constructor.

**Good Read:**
[What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361)

Comment: @tenfour: *"How can I overwrite the bar method in `FooBar`, while still being able to use all the other `foo` methods without defining them again?"* seems pretty clear/intuitive to me.

Comment: It's not clear if he wants hiding or overriding; is he trying to usurp the behavior of code that uses `FooBar` objects? Or does he just want to create new objects that conveniently inherit stuff that `FooBar` does?